# Cognos Calculate Variance between dates

Tags: pivot-table, cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

I have a "Master data" list like this :

| Description | Snapchot - Date | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| XXX | 2023-01-05 | 150 |
| XXX | 2023-01-05 | 100 |
| XXX | 2023-01-06 | 350 |
| XXX | 2023-01-07 | 200 |

My goal is to create a Pivot table that calculates difference with day before :

```
     |  2023-01-05   |  2023-01-06   |  2023-01-07   |
     | Value | Diff. | Value | Diff. | Value | Diff. |
------------------------------------------------------
XXX  |  250  |   0   |  350  |  100  |  200  | -150  |
```

My problem is that I don't know how to make my calculation between two time periods :

```
(Value of [Snapchot - Date]) - (Value of ([Snapchot - Date] - 1 day)
```

What I tried is to make a second query where I use this expression :

```
add_days_ ([Snapchot - Date] ; -1)
```

This works but there's a mismatch in my values. I don't have the correct values for every dates as I have in my master list.

How can I create a query that gives me the value of the day before ? So that I can do :

```
[ValueCurrentDay] - [ValueDayBefore]
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the requirement you maybe looking for a running-difference.  Have a look at the summary folder for the syntax of that summary function to see if it applies to your requirement.

Comment: This might me a solution yes, the problem is that in my List, the Description (XXX) might change so when the XXX line will switch to YYY, I will have a problem. Do you have something that can counter this ?

Comment: An example of the data changing would probably be best, but you might require the for clause.  So running-difference(column for description)

Comment: To make this clearer, please create a report using the samples data -- GO Sales (query) works well -- that reproduces the problem and post the report spec.  The answer provided by @DanielWagemann seems correct to me, so I don't understand what problems remain.  Before complaining about the answer not working, you did read the documentation and tips for `running-difference`, right?